# How to generate a power-law / pink noise signal?

Tags: random-process, probability-distribution-function, power-law

Suppose I need to generate a time series where the intervals will be about 120 seconds every time, but with a small variation (e.g. 125, 130, 119, 118, 121, 129, etc)

I want this variation not to be random, but to, rather, follow the power-law distribution, so there will be a few, but significant number of big variations and most of them will be small (+-2-3 seconds).

Is there an algorithm that you know of in Javascript that could perform this? Or at least direct me to some sort of function that can generate this sort of distribution that will be always around a certain number (e.g. 120 in my case)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by generating a zero mean pink noise signal $p[n]$ and then just scale bias it, i.e. your intervals will be

$x[n] = 120 + k\cdot p[n]$

where $k$ controls how far the interval will swing around 120.

Pink noise can be generated either by filtering white noise or by creating the magnitude spectrum directly in the frequency domain adding a random phase and performing and inverse FFT. For a filtering example, see [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Example_Synthesis_1_F_Noise.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Example_Synthesis_1_F_Noise.html)

In practice most pink noise signals are only pink down to a lower limit frequency since otherwise the theoretically unlimited energy at very low frequencies becomes unwieldy.